# MySql PHPmyadmin error #1062

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have an when i try to put in a sql-query in my retro (r63) database i get this error\
SQL-query:

```
INSERT INTO `dice`.`wordfilter` (`word`, `replacement`, `strict`) VALUES ('Kut', '***', '1'), ('kanker', '****', '1')
```

MySQL meldt: Documentatie

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Kut' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

this is the code i use (it's dutch)

```
INSERT INTO `dice`.`wordfilter` (`word`, `replacement`, `strict`) VALUES ('Kut', '***', '1'), ('kanker', '****', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database is designed to require that the `word` column contains a *unique* value.

Since you already have an entry for "Kut", you can't have another one.

Either:

1. change the design of your database
2. use a different word
3. use an UPDATE statement instead of an INSERT statement

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to phpmyadmin as such. It is a SQL error.  `word` in your table is primary key.

Solution: Remove the primary key (add another one if needed - a simple id).

Or perhaps you just wanted an index in column `word` but added a primary key?